# Model binding and validation в gin golang

Tags: golang, swagger

Новичок в gin.
Есть такой стракт с тегами:

```
type BookSeries struct {
    PageParametersQuery
    Sort  BookSeriesSort `json:"sort" example:"price,createdAt,updatedAt" enums:"price,createdAt,updatedAt"` // Тип сортировки
    Order Order          `json:"order" form:"order" enums:"asc,desc"`                                        // Направление сортировки
}
```

Про теги json, form читал в официальной документации.
Теги example, enums не нашел.
Может они кастомные?
Подскажите пожалуйста где почитать про такие нестандартные теги?